# t-test on R with multiple grouped variables

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics, grouping, t-test

I have a dataset like this

| long_id | short_id | quants | treatment | avg_amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7210 | 721015 | Short | 0 | 2528582.92 |
| 7210 | 721015 | Medium | 0 | 1893851.78 |
| 7210 | 721015 | Long | 0 | 2274530.74 |
| 7210 | 721015 | Short | 1 | 1301169.80 |
| 7210 | 721015 | Medium | 1 | 1442934.90 |
| 7210 | 721015 | Long | 1 | 1582988.01 |
| 7210 | 721022 | Short | 0 | 1569400.78 |
| 7210 | 721022 | Medium | 0 | 25463492.9 |
| 7210 | 721022 | Long | 0 | 58901706.6 |
| 7210 | 721022 | Short | 1 | 81037294.1 |
| 7210 | 721022 | Medium | 1 | 1491750.90 |
| 7210 | 721022 | Long | 1 | 8721906.01 |

And so on for multiple IDs. I also have the same version of the dataset in wide format, with the "0" that becomes treatment_0 variable, and "1" that becomes "treatment_1" variable.

I'd like to do a t-test in order to compare the means of avg_amount for both treatment 0/1, but by grouping also with long and short IDs, as well as quants variable.

Here is what i tried :

```
stat.test <- df %>%
  group_by(short_id, long_id, quants) %>%
  t_test(avg_amount ~ treatment ) %>%
  adjust_pvalue(method = "BH") %>%
  add_significance()
```

> Error : Problem with `mutate()` column `data`.
> ℹ `data = map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
> x not enough 'x' observations

```
df2 <- data_wide %>% 
  group_by(short_id, long_id, quants) %>% 
  do(tidy(t.test(.$treatment_0,
                 .$treatment_1,
                 mu = 0, 
                 alt = "two.sided", 
                 paired = F, 
                 conf.level = 0.99)))
```

> Error in t.test.default(.$treatment_0, .$treatment_1, mu = 0, alt = "two.sided",  : not enough 'x' observations

-> Also tried with "paired=T" but the result is the same.

```
stat.test <- df %>%
+   group_by(short_id,long_id treatment, quants, avg_amount) %>%
+   t_test(avg_amount ~ treatment ) %>%
+   adjust_pvalue(method = "BH") %>%
+   add_significance()
```

> Error : Problem with `mutate()` column `data`.
> ℹ `data = map(.data$data, .f, ...)`.
> x Can't extract columns that don't exist.
> x Column `treatment` doesn't exist.

It's the 1st time I need to run a t-test like that.

Comment: Is it possible you do not have every combination of short_id, long_id and quants? Try running this to count the number of members in each group: `data_wide %>% group_by(short_id, long_id, quants, treatment) %>% summarize(counts=n())`

Comment: @Dave2e all my counts are equal to 1 so i suppose that is right ? I found a topic here about these errors, saying that is probably an encoding problem in the variables' names. But i found no problem with the names() and the dput() so i'm lost.

Comment: One point per group is not enough data to perform a t-test.  You will have to group with less variables.  For example “group_by(short_id, long_id)” should work, but with only 3 points for each treatment it is a low power test.

Comment: Oh okay now i understand ! It was the grouping by long_id that caused the problem. I grouped with the short_id and quants and i obtained something ! Now i have to figure out how to interpret this big table ! Thanks !